# How to detect when user open browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I  am writing a chrome extension and I need to detect when the user opens his/her browser, but I do not know how.

Can you please help me with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome extensions have a background js file, which is run, when the browser starts.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I need to write some listener :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to register a listener for the `onStartup` event in your background script with `chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(callback)`

In your manifest file make sure you have a entry specifying which script file to run in your background page, and whether it should be persistent or not.

`"background": {
  "scripts": ["js/event.js"],
  "persistent": false
},`